# Add data to a zip archive until it reaches a given size

Tags: c#, .net, compression

I'm trying to zip some data, but also break up the data set into multiple archives so that no single zip file ends up being larger than some maximum.

Since my data is not sourced from the file system it seems a good idea to use a streaming approach. I thought I could simply write one atomic piece of data at a a time while keeping track of the stream position prior to writing each piece. Once I exceed the limit, I truncate the stream to the position before writing the piece that can't fit, and move on to create the next archive.

I've attempted with the classes in System.IO.Compression - create an archive, create an entry, use ZipArchiveEntry.Open to get a stream, and write to that stream. The problem is it seems impossible to get from this how large the archive is at any point.

I can read the stream's position, but this is tracking uncompressed bytes. Truncating the stream works fine too, so I have this working as intended now with the important exception that the limit applies to how much uncompressed data there is per archive rather than how large the compressed archive becomes.

The data is part compressible text and various blobs (attachments from end users) that will sometimes be very compressible and sometimes not at all.

My questions:

1) Is there something about the deflate algorithm that inherently conflicts with my approach? I know it is a block-based compression scheme and I imagine the algorithm may not decide how to encode the compressed data until the *entire archive* has been specified.

2) If the answer to (1) above is "yes", what is a good strategy that doesn't introduce far too much overhead?

One idea I have is to assume that compressed data won't be larger than uncompressed data. I can then write to the stream until uncompressed data exceeds the threshold, and then save the archive, calculate the difference between the threshold and the current size, and repeat until full.

In case that wasn't clear, say the limit is 1MB. I write 1 MB of uncompressed data and save the archive. I then see that the resulting archive is 0.3MB. I open the archive (and its only entry) again and start over with a new limit of 0.7 MB, since I know I am able to add at least that much uncompressed data to it without overshooting. I imagine this approach is relatively simple to implement, and will test it, but am interested to hear if anyone has better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out a lower bound on how big the compressed data is by looking at the `Length` or `Position` of the underlying `FileStream`. You can then decide to stop adding entries. The ZIP stream classes tend to buffer not too much. Probably on the order of 64KB.

Truncating the archive at a certain point should be possible. Try flushing the ZIP stream before measuring the `Position` of the base stream. This is always possible in theory but the actual library you are using might not support it. Test it or look at the source.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't write anything to the underlying stream until the entire archive (whether one or multiple entries in the zip) is closed. Looking at it in the debugger, the stream returned from ZipArchiveEntry.Open uses a MemoryStream as its basestream - seems a bit like I all that happens as I write to the stream is that I fill up an *input* buffer, and no actual zipping occurs until the archive is being closed. The library I am using is .NET Framework 4.5 (System.IO.Compression namespace). :)

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about that BCL feature. But I *do* know that it had horrible compression in .NET 4.0. Maybe still. Use a better lib, like SharpZipLib. It does not buffer the entire archive. ZIP is not a solid format. No need to buffer (much).